# The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request

Tags: python, html

I am a newbie to the python. I was trying with a simple python script and HTML as given below code:

html code- ex1.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<head>  
<title>demo web file python3.2</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form name="pyform" method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/form.py">  
  <input type="text" name="fname" />  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

And Python script-form.py

```
#!"C:\python34\python.exe"
print("Content-Type: text/html")      
print()                               

import cgi,cgitb  
cgitb.enable() #for debugging  
form = cgi.FieldStorage()  
name = form.getvalue('fname')  
print("Name of the user is:",name)
```

and executed in local host as 
http://localhost/cgi-bin/ex1.html

giving error as

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

Comment: nice tutorial..I hv  tried with simple programs  from that tutorial but  getting a same error. Is it some kind of setting problem .but simple print  hello world program in python will work